# Have a column to automatically calculate when a value is entered into a different column

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a table of data that I input a value into Col2. What I want is Col3 in the table to automatically calculate when I input the value. I don't want to use a formula unless that is my only option.

| Date | Val | Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12/6/2023 | 300 | 300 |
| 12/7/2023 | 128 | 428 |
| 12/8/2023 | 200 | 628 |

I have a basic formula that I use but I prefer to use apps script.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Regarding `I have a basic formula that I use but I prefer to use apps script.` , how are the totals calculated?

Comment: @Codedabbler Row1) Total = Val         Row2) Total = Row1_Total + Row2 Val       Row3) Total = Row2_Total + Row3_Val

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
function setFormulaValues() {

  setFormula();
  setValues();

}

function setFormula() {
  
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

// This inserts a column in the second column position

sheet.getRange(2,3).setFormula('=B2')
sheet.getRange(3,3,sheet.getLastRow(),1).setFormula('=(IF(B3<>"",C2+B3,))');

SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}

function setValues() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var range = sheet.getRange("A2:C");

// Copy and paste the values where you want to
range.copyValuesToRange(sheet,1,3,2,sheet.getLastRow());

SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  
}
```

**Note:**  This code is written as if your table structure represents Sheet!A1:C.  If not, you will have to change the Sheet Name and/or the ranges within the code.

The code inserts a formula,then copies the range, and replaces the formulas in the range with the values only.

Comment: Works like a charm. I had zero idea of where to start with this besides using a formula.  Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

This uses an onEdit function that triggers on any access of your sheet in column 2 except for row 1.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast("entry");//debugging
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() != "Your Sheet Name" || e.range.columnStart != 2 || e.range.rowStart == 1)return;
  //e.source.toast("gate");//debugging
  let o = sh.getRange(2,2,sh.getLastRow() - 1).getValues().flat().reduce((a,v,i) => {
    a.sum += Number(v);
    a.arr.push([a.sum]);
    return a;
  },{sum:0,arr:[]});
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(o));//debugging
  sh.getRange(2,3,o.arr.length,o.arr[0].length).setValues(o.arr);
}
```

You cannot run these functions without supplying the event object. If you attempt to run from the script editor without supplying the event object you will get an error.  The onEdit trigger is a simple trigger meaning that it cannot perform functions that require permission.  If you need to perform commands that require permission you must create an installable trigger either programmatically or through the editors trigger panel.

There are several limitations running scripts this way.  You will have difficulty using alert and prompt boxes.  They are fairly difficult to debug because the onEdit is not easily run in debug mode so you are left having to edit the appropriate elements on the desired sheet.

If you wish to view the complete onEdit event object try this:

```
function onMyEdit(e){Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e))};
//{""authMode"":""FULL"",""oldValue"":""10.0"",""range"":{""columnEnd"":6,""columnStart"":6,""rowEnd"":6,""rowStart"":6},""source"":{},""triggerUid"":"""",""user"":{""email"":"""",""nickname"":""""},""value"":""pp""}
```